# CSS nesting properties... At least I hope that's what it's called

Tags: css, nested

I was wondering if there was a way to use css to style a wrapper a certain way ONLY if it had a div with a specific id inside. **Let's say** that I have

```
<div class="intro_wrapper"></div>
```

in several places throughout the site but want to change the padding ONLY if it

```
<div class="intro_wrapper">
    <div id="slider"></div>
</div>
```

has `#slider` inside of it. The thing is that I want to make it have less padding when `#slider` is nested in it so I can't really mess with the margin for `#slider` without cutting off the content all weird. I tried using negative margins but it ends up cutting off the image I have in a weird way.

I know you can use stuff like `p + p` for paragraphs that have paragraphs following them, so I am assuming there may be a way to do something like I am trying to. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Unfortunately, no. But it seems there will be a ["subject" selector](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1014861/is-there-a-css-parent-selector) in the future that would allow that (`.intro_wrapper! #slider`)

Comment: Yeah I just found a post that said that will apparently be with CSS4??

Comment: @OneTrickPony: [sort of, but not](http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors4/#profiles) (unfortunately); though I'm hoping this will be revised prior to CSS 4's actual release-candidate, ignored by browser vendors and implemented anyway or, perhaps (at worst) that CSS 4 will be a beta-test for implementation details, and it might be included in CSS 5 (for real).

Comment: Well, that's a shame because many people expect this functionality :(

Comment: @OneTrickPony: absolutely. I *want this* (I'd also prefer to use the `:subject` pseudo-class, rather than arbitrary punctuation; it appears the working group live to frustrate my desires, however).

Comment: @DavidThomas 90% of my jQuery usage is because of the frustrating gaps in the capabilities of CSS selectors

Answer (score 4):

You cannot do that with any CSS rules at this point as a reverse combinator to apply style on parent based on child. Instead you can hack it by adding a margin to the child instead.

```
div.intro_wrapper > #slider
{
  margin:20px;
}
```

Comment: Yeah my issue is a bit more complex than that but was using the padding just for sake of making the question easy to ask.

Comment: @user1470242 You should edit the question to remove that possibility for misinterpretation.

Comment: @user1470242 there is no way at this point. So you can probably go with these lines something like adding a wrapper (which has margin) to the contents inside the `intro_wrapper` incase of your particular div's presence. But i don't know your scenario though.

Comment: Alright sorry about that. Still learning how to properly ask questions here

Comment: Oh well it did say "Let's say" but I bolded it to emphasize that it's more hypothetical.

Comment: @user1470242: can you edit the question to clearly explain what problem/situation you're trying to solve (or what effect you're trying to achieve)? That way, perhaps, we can avoid the closure of a (potentially/presumably) valid question.

Comment: @user1470242 That still doesn't highlight the fact that the property you want to change isn't specifically padding.

Comment: Updated it. Hope that helps.

Comment: @user1470242: well, no: you've still not explained the actual problem that you're trying to solve. So, as yet, this should still be closed as a duplicate (which I don't want to do, since I'd rather help you address the problem and reach a solution that's of use to you and, hopefully, others in future).

Comment: @user1470242: I don't want to, I *want* to help; but I *can't*, because I, and others (as of writing), don't know what you're having trouble with (though we understand the broad outlines). If, however, *you* want to close the question, you may be able to click the 'delete' link below the question's tags.

Comment: I don't see why this is such a big issue? The question may not describe his problem clearly (or correctly) but there are at least a couple of useful answers here which seem to have helped him. Deleting the question would definitely be overkill imo

Comment: It's quite obvious he's asking for a parent-selector-type solution, all three answers so far have managed to pick up on this.

Answer (score 1):

Whilst I think PSL's answer is already pretty good (cross browser, simple etc.) it doesn't help if you actually need to use a parent selector. Whilst at the moment it's best to avoid this when you can, there are definitely some circumstances which may require a parent selector (or some such alternative).

One solution if you absolutely have to use a parent selector would be jquery, its selector engine recongnises the [:parent](http://api.jquery.com/parent-selector/) selector, for example you could do:

```
$("#slider:parent").addClass('padded_intro_wrapper');
```

Then in your CSS:

```
.padded_intro_wrapper
{
  padding: 20px;
}
```

Equally, if the `#slider` div isn't always inside the `.intro_wrapper` div you could do:

```
$('#slider').closest('.intro_wrapper').addClass('padded_intro_wrapper');
```

That's where it starts getting a bit messy though.

**EDIT:** [Fiddle if you're feeling lazy](http://jsfiddle.net/e6B4z/)

Comment: Cool... I'm not that great at jquery but I appreciate it. I'll see if I can figure out how to get that to work.

Comment: Added a fiddle if that helps :)

Comment: I wasn't sure if you'd be using jQuery or not (I don't use it with every project) so unfortunately this answer isn't universal, but as far as I know it's the only way to implement the parent selector as you described without a lot of hard work.

Comment: Oh sweet. Where would I put that on my page? Do I need to link to any script library or anything?

Comment: You'd need to link to jQuery somewhere on the page, most people recommend using the Google CDN for it: https://developers.google.com/speed/libraries/devguide#jquery

Comment: Other than that, just put either of the above snippets in a `script` block just before you closing `</body>` tag, and you should be good to go :)

Comment: And then I add the jquery between script tags?

Comment: Yep that's right, like this `<script type="text/javascript"> $('#slider').closest('.intro_wrapper').addClass('padded_intro_wrapper'); </script>`